# Remove entities from collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables; Groups, Customers, and GroupCustomers.  Groups can have many customers, hence the reason for the GroupCustomers table.  In my C# WinForms program, I am trying to delete all the Customers for a specific Group using Linq.  Here's my code that seems to work but it I think I am missing something to make this query a lot smaller/easier/faster to read & execute.

```
Context.Groups.Where(g => g.Id == group.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                        .Customers.ToList()
                        .ForEach(gc =>
                            {
                                Context.Groups.Where(g => g.Id == group.Id)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault()
                                                            .Customers.Remove(gc);
                            });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

`group.Id` is a variable that is passed into this method.

Comment: To start with, you can skip `Where` and just pass the predicate to `FirstOrDefault`. Also note that `FirstOrDefault` can return `null`. I really urge you to check that, or just go with `First` which I think will give you a better / more readable exception in case of a group missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're too stuck on LINQ. I'd write this:

```
 var group = Context.Groups.First(g => g.Id == group.Id); // if you're sure of existing
 foreach (var customer in group.Customers.ToList()) // ToList is required to avoid 'Collection was modified' exception, I think
      Context.Customers.Remove(customer);
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You are removing the customers from the context altogether whereas the OP is just removing them from a particular group.

Comment: @Rune, when got a group object, I enumerate *it*'s navigation property - `group.Customers`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query to select all the items you wish to remove.  You wish to remove all customers that are within a particular group.  That would correspond to the `GroupCustomers` that was created to link the two.  Select those, then remove them.

```
var toBeRemoved =
    from gc in Context.GroupCustomers
    where gc.GroupId == group.Id
    select gc;
foreach (var gc in toBeRemoved)
    Context.GroupCustomers.DeleteObject(gc);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

---

Otherwise, what you have is logically fine, but I would make a few adjustments.  Select the group to remove customers from and remove the customers from the group.  `.ToList().ForEach()` should *never* be used as a substitute for a regular call to `foreach`.

```
var removeFromGroup = Context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == group.Id);
foreach (var c in removeFromGroup.Customers)
    removeFromGroup.Remove(c);
Context.SaveChanges();
```